# Gantt chart with resource input

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to create a Gantt chart that allows the user to add or remove resource to a certain project, therefore adjusting the end date accordingly. Within the data tab I have been able to do this as the resource comes in with that data as a static figure and I've created several calculated columns to achieve this. However, when turning them all into measures and getting the visual reacting to it correctly, I'm running into problems.

So just to confirm, I can do this within the data tab, but I'm trying to do this so the user can dynamically change this end date figure, which is why I need them as measures.

This is my current calculation that isn't working.

`IF(SelectedResource] = 1 , [DurationHours] - [Rec hours] * [DurationHours], etc etc`

**Duration hours** is a date diff between the start and end date

**Rec hours** is based on the number of resource clicked (So if 1 is selected, one person works a 6 hour day, so 6 is returned)

I've tried different functions like calculate, sum etc and still no luck. Any help would be apricated. First post so if this is in the wrong pace or I've missed something let me know.

Cheers